# Render a partial layout in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I am trying to build a demo app like square space. I have a preview page where an iframe loads the template that was selected. So I decided that I wont be needing the default layout (application.html.erb). I created a new folder called Design1 in views and inside it created another folder called partials. I made _header.html.erb inside of it. I created another file called home.blade.php inside the Design1 folder and tried to include the 'layouts/header' in it and it gives me this err

```
Missing partial Design1/_header with {:locale=>[:en], :formats=>[:html], :variants=>[], :handlers=>[:erb, :builder, :raw, :ruby, :coffee, :jbuilder]}. Searched in: * "/usr/share/nginx/html/fuitter-test/app/views"
```

this is how I am rendering the header file in home.html.erb

```
<%= render 'layouts/header' %>
```

my forlder structuer

```
views
  -Design1
    -layouts
      - _header.html.erb
    -home.html.erb
  -other folders
```

And I have also done

```
layout false
```

in the controller

Comment: Please show partial render code.

Comment: May be ```Design1``` must be included to ```render```'s argument?
```<%= render 'Design1/layouts/header' %>```

Comment: see my answer, the bottom path. if you really wanna go /Design1/ you need to prepend the view_paths

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First of all - **always** downcase on file names! Never use *Design* or *MyCoolStory*, in rails we use *convention over configuration* and that means **snake_case** which is everything downcased and separated with **_under_scores**

To your render issues:
There is a great documentation where you'll find anything you need: http://guides.rubyonrails.org/layouts_and_rendering.html

Let me help you a little.

Rails is looking for a **Layout**. By default it will be expected in **/app/views/layouts/application.html.erb** (there is nothing wrong with keeping it named as application). A Layout is the whole HTML Frame you will need. Within the Layout there (should) always be a `yield`block. 
A YieldBlock in rails is where your templates are rendered into.

so basically a layout-file can look like this (i use haml for easier reading)

```
%html
  %head
    =render "shared/head"
  %body
    .wrapper
      %nav.navigation=render "shared/navigation"
      .main_content
        =yield
      %footer.foot=render "shared/footer"
```

This means you are having 3 partial-templates in **/app/views/shared** named *_head.html.erb*, *_navigation.html.erb* and *_footer.html.erb*

That's the rails way.

---

**Further informations**

If you are planning to have a multi-design app, you should structure your views in total like

- /app/views/design1
- /app/views/design2
- /app/views/design3
- /app/views/shared

and set the lookup path in your controller like this

```
prepend_view_path "#{Rails.root}/app/views/#{design_path}"
def design_path
  current_page.design_name
end
```

By then, all views will be looked up into their specified folder (Spree multi_store engine, is doing like this, for an example)

Answer (score 2):

You put your `layouts` folder in `Design1` folder, thus you should use following path to render your layout:

```
<%= render 'Design1/layouts/header' %>
```

Answer (score 1):

The render structure should be starting from the `/views` folder.

```
<%= render 'Design1/layouts/header' %>
```